# Descent equation and anomaly polynomial

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, quantum-anomalies

I am just reading Ryu, Moore and Ludwig's paper on [classifications of topological insulators and quantum anomaly](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0936). They are trying to relate the quantum anomaly as a signal of the presence of a topological phase in higher dimension. However, the descent equation they used in their paper has the sign different from the usual descent equations. I am wondering why do they need to change the sign?

Comment: -1. Unclear. Which equation? Which sign? What are the 'usual' descent equations?